# nullable primarykey

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables.

Purchase:

- `PurchaseId`
- `SenderId`
- `ReceiverId`

Customers:

- `Customerid` (Primary-unique)
- `CUSID` (Not primary-not unique-Allow null)
- `FirsName`
- `LastName`

I want to make some reports from all purchase with username and lastnames in customers table.
I cannot make any relation.All my codes give me error or return wrong results.
Please help me.(the values of receiver and sender are equal CUSID in customers Table)
The relations are wrong:as I cannot make any primary key as my field is allow null.

```
(select (tbl_Customers.FirstName + '-' +  tbl_Customers.LastName) as receiver
FROM         tbl_PurchaseForms
INNER JOIN
tbl_Customers ON tbl_PurchaseForms.ReceiverUId = tbl_Customers.CUSID) 
or
(select (tbl_Customers.FirstName + '-' +  tbl_Customers.LastName) as sender
FROM         tbl_PurchaseForms
INNER JOIN
tbl_Customers ON tbl_PurchaseForms.SenderUId = tbl_Customers.CUSID)
```

Comment: SQL Server's requirements for a primary key are : **NOT NULLABLE** and unique. You **CANNOT** define a nullable primary key.

Answer (score 0):

I'm admittedly a little confused by your question, but it sounds like you're attempting to return all the customers who have either received or sent something from your purchase table, linking on your cusid field?

If so, something like this should work (I've included an extra column called purchase type if you need to distinguish between senders and receivers):

```
SELECT 
    'Sender' as PurchaseType, 
    C.FirstName, 
    C.LastName
FROM Customers C 
    JOIN Purchase P ON C.CUSID  = P.SenderId
UNION 
SELECT 
    'Receiver' as PurchaseType, 
    C.FirstName, 
    C.LastName
FROM Customers C 
    JOIN Purchase P ON C.CUSID  = P.ReceiverId
```

Good luck.

Comment: Still confused -- you can join on any fields, including NULL ones -- you do not have to join on primary keys -- presumably, if CUSID is null, you don't want to return that data.  Here is some SQL Fiddle to try to help you: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/408de/2

Comment: PurchaseId  SenderId SenderName ReceiverId ReceiverName               1            25       Corey      13         Alex                      2             65      Tom         87        Adam (Names come from customer table join Customerid(not primary and allow null) and senderid,receiverid(not primary not null)

Comment: SELECT     tbl_PurchaseForms.PurchaseId,
tbl_PurchaseForms.SenderUId,
(select (tbl_Customers.FirstName + '-' +  tbl_Customers.LastName)
FROM  tbl_PurchaseForms
JOIN
tbl_Customers ON tbl_PurchaseForms.SenderUId = tbl_Customers.CUSID) as SenderName,
tbl_PurchaseForms.ReceiverUId,(select (tbl_Customers.FirstName + '-' +  tbl_Customers.LastName)
FROM tbl_PurchaseForms JOIN tbl_Customers ON tbl_PurchaseForms.ReceiverUId = tbl_Customers.CUSID)as ReceiverName, tbl_PurchaseForms.FCY,FROM tbl_PurchaseForms INNER JOIN tbl_Currency ON tbl_PurchaseForms.FCY = tbl_Currency.CurrencyId (all purchases return)

Comment: forget about allow null in cusid. union is not useful as returns more than one result and it gives error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select p.*
,(Select  c.FirstName + '-' +  c.LastName  from customers c where c.CUSID  = P.ReceiverId) as  receiver
,(Select  c.FirstName + '-' +  c.LastName  from customers c where c.CUSID  = P.SenderId) as  Sender
from purchase p
```

while Purchase should be designed to enable this

```
Select p.*
,(Select  c.FirstName + '-' +  c.LastName  from customers c where c.Customerid  = P.ReceiverId) as  receiver
,(Select  c.FirstName + '-' +  c.LastName  from customers c where c.Customerid  = P.SenderId) as  Sender
from purchase p
```

Comment: sorry the result is not true.I did it before.

Comment: what about the final join between customers table and purchase?how can I write the join?FROM         finex.tbl_PurchaseForms
                      join tbl_customers on tbl_PurchaseForms.SenderUId=tbl_customers.CUSID                    it gets error.
                      join tbl_customers on tbl_PurchaseForms.ReceiverUId=tbl_customers.CUSID

Comment: Thanks every one.I made it.